# SQL Query - Specify how to select a particular column

Tags: sql, sql-server

A forewarning: I am not a SQL Dev.  I am looking at this query and trying to modify it to resolve an issue with the results.

I have the follow query which works (syntactically):

```
SELECT
    MIN(issue_time) AS incident_time,
    MIN(issue_status) AS issue_status,
    MIN(monitor_start_time) AS monitor_start_time,
    MAX(resolved_time) AS resolved_time,
    incident_id,
    MAX(model_handle) AS model_handle,
    device_retrieval_id,
    MAX(last_status_time) AS last_status_time,
    MAX(last_analysis_time) AS last_analysis_time,
    n.node_name,
    MAX(last_problem_time) AS last_problem_time,
    SUM(problem_count) AS problem_count
FROM (
    SELECT
        issue_time, issue_status, monitor_start_time, resolved_time, incident_id,
        model_handle, device_retrieval_id, last_status_time, last_analysis_time,
        last_problem_time, problem_count
    FROM x_network_device_node_status
    UNION
    SELECT
        issue_time, issue_status, monitor_start_time, resolved_time, incident_id,
        model_handle, device_retrieval_id, last_status_time, last_analysis_time,
        last_problem_time, problem_count
    FROM x_network_device_node_status_hist
    WHERE incident_id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT incident_id
        FROM (
            SELECT incident_id
            FROM x_network_device_node_status
            UNION
            SELECT incident_id
            FROM x_network_device_node_status_hist
            WHERE issue_time >= '2016-12-10'
        ) AS i
    )
) AS x LEFT JOIN
x_nodes AS n ON x.device_retrieval_id = n.node_retrieval_id
GROUP BY incident_id, device_retrieval_id, node_name
ORDER BY incident_time DESC;
```

I recently realized that that we should not be selecting the `MAX(resolved_time) AS resolved_time`, but instead should be getting the `resolved_time` for each `incident_id` from the record with the most recent `issue_time`.

For example, if the UNION of records in the database for a particular incident_id was:

```
╔═════════════════════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═══════════════╗
║       issue_time        ║ issue_status ║   monitor_start_time    ║      resolved_time      ║     incident_id     ║ model_handle ║ device_retrieval_id ║    last_status_time     ║   last_analysis_time    ║    last_problem_time    ║ problem_count ║
╠═════════════════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2016-12-13 17:15:00.000 ║            1 ║ 2016-12-13 17:46:28.000 ║ 2016-12-13 18:16:34.000 ║ 1427068756009427097 ║     85983911 ║           332265337 ║ 2016-12-13 18:16:34.000 ║ 2016-12-13 18:01:28.000 ║ NULL                    ║             0 ║
║ 2016-12-13 18:15:00.000 ║            1 ║ NULL                    ║ 2016-12-13 18:31:28.000 ║ 1427068756009427097 ║     85983911 ║           332265337 ║ 2016-12-13 18:31:28.000 ║ NULL                    ║ NULL                    ║             0 ║
║ 2016-12-13 18:31:28.000 ║            2 ║ 2016-12-14 09:16:28.000 ║ 2016-12-15 08:31:30.000 ║ 1427068756009427097 ║     85983911 ║           332265337 ║ 2016-12-15 08:31:30.000 ║ 2016-12-15 08:16:28.000 ║ 2016-12-15 08:16:28.000 ║             6 ║
║ 2016-12-15 08:30:00.000 ║            1 ║ 2016-12-15 10:01:31.000 ║ 2016-12-15 11:46:28.000 ║ 1427068756009427097 ║     85983911 ║           332265337 ║ 2016-12-15 11:46:28.000 ║ 2016-12-15 11:31:31.000 ║ 2016-12-15 11:31:31.000 ║             3 ║
║ 2016-12-15 11:45:00.000 ║            1 ║ NULL                    ║ 2016-12-15 12:01:31.000 ║ 1427068756009427097 ║     85983911 ║           332265337 ║ 2016-12-15 12:01:31.000 ║ NULL                    ║ NULL                    ║             0 ║
║ 2016-12-15 12:00:00.000 ║            1 ║ 2016-12-15 12:16:28.000 ║ 2016-12-15 12:31:29.000 ║ 1427068756009427097 ║     85983911 ║           332265337 ║ 2016-12-15 12:31:29.000 ║ NULL                    ║ NULL                    ║             0 ║
║ 2016-12-15 12:30:00.000 ║            1 ║ NULL                    ║ 2016-12-15 13:01:31.000 ║ 1427068756009427097 ║     85983911 ║           332265337 ║ 2016-12-15 13:01:31.000 ║ NULL                    ║ NULL                    ║             0 ║
║ 2016-12-15 13:01:31.000 ║            2 ║ 2016-12-15 16:46:28.000 ║ NULL                    ║ 1427068756009427097 ║     85983911 ║           332265337 ║ 2016-12-15 22:31:28.000 ║ 2016-12-15 22:31:28.000 ║ 2016-12-15 17:31:28.000 ║             2 ║
╚═════════════════════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

I would like the result to be:

```
╔═════════════════════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═══════════════╦═════════════════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═══════════════╗
║      incident_time      ║ issue_status ║   monitor_start_time    ║ resolved_time ║     incident_id     ║ model_handle ║ device_retrieval_id ║    last_status_time     ║   last_analysis_time    ║ node_name  ║    last_problem_time    ║ problem_count ║
╠═════════════════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2016-12-13 17:15:00.000 ║            1 ║ 2016-12-13 17:46:28.000 ║ NULL          ║ 1427068756009427097 ║     85983911 ║           332265337 ║ 2016-12-15 22:31:28.000 ║ 2016-12-15 22:31:28.000 ║ MyNodeName ║ 2016-12-15 17:31:28.000 ║            11 ║
╚═════════════════════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═══════════════╩═════════════════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

But instead, it is coming back as:

```
╔═════════════════════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═══════════════╗
║      incident_time      ║ issue_status ║   monitor_start_time    ║      resolved_time      ║     incident_id     ║ model_handle ║ device_retrieval_id ║    last_status_time     ║   last_analysis_time    ║ node_name  ║    last_problem_time    ║ problem_count ║
╠═════════════════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2016-12-13 17:15:00.000 ║            1 ║ 2016-12-13 17:46:28.000 ║ 2016-12-15 13:01:31.000 ║ 1427068756009427097 ║     85983911 ║           332265337 ║ 2016-12-15 22:31:28.000 ║ 2016-12-15 22:31:28.000 ║ MyNodeName ║ 2016-12-15 17:31:28.000 ║            11 ║
╚═════════════════════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  MIN(issue_time) AS incident_time,
  MIN(issue_status) AS issue_status,
  MIN(monitor_start_time) AS monitor_start_time,
  (SELECT TOP 1 xxx.resolved_time
   FROM
    (SELECT xx.issue_time,xx.resolved_time
     FROM x_network_device_node_status xx
     WHERE xx.incident_id=x.incident_id
     UNION ALL
     SELECT xx2.issue_time,xx2.resolved_time
     FROM x_network_device_node_status_hist xx2
     WHERE xx2.incident_id=x.incident_id) AS xxx
   ORDER BY xxx.issue_time DESC) AS resolved_time,
  incident_id,
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the syntax, but the idea is to use CTE and query it.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(SELECT
    issue_time, issue_status, monitor_start_time, resolved_time, incident_id,
    model_handle, device_retrieval_id, last_status_time, last_analysis_time,
    last_problem_time, problem_count
FROM x_network_device_node_status
UNION
SELECT
    issue_time, issue_status, monitor_start_time, resolved_time, incident_id,
    model_handle, device_retrieval_id, last_status_time, last_analysis_time,
    last_problem_time, problem_count
FROM x_network_device_node_status_hist
WHERE incident_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT incident_id
    FROM (
        SELECT incident_id
        FROM x_network_device_node_status
        UNION
        SELECT incident_id
        FROM x_network_device_node_status_hist
        WHERE issue_time >= '2016-12-10'
    ) AS i
)
)
SELECT
MIN(issue_time) AS incident_time,
MIN(issue_status) AS issue_status,
MIN(monitor_start_time) AS monitor_start_time,
(SELECT resolved_time FROM CTE WHERE issue_time = (SELECT MAX(issue_time) FROM CTE)) AS resolved_time,
incident_id,
MAX(model_handle) AS model_handle,
device_retrieval_id,
MAX(last_status_time) AS last_status_time,
MAX(last_analysis_time) AS last_analysis_time,
n.node_name,
MAX(last_problem_time) AS last_problem_time,
SUM(problem_count) AS problem_count
FROM CTE AS x LEFT JOIN
x_nodes AS n ON x.device_retrieval_id = n.node_retrieval_id
GROUP BY incident_id, device_retrieval_id, node_name
ORDER BY incident_time DESC;
```